# Save instance of handle object

Tags: matlab

I'm currently working on a project that will later have electronics integrated into it. I want to have some simulated data for two things to use, but in the real system I will pull the processed data from the electronics, so there are two different places that need it and would eventually just pull from the electronics, however right now they can't. To simulate it I could have a handle class that holds the processed data (like a 512x512 array so I don't want to save and load a bunch) and pull that data in both places, but the problem is that there's no way of passing unless the information climbs the whole class hierarchy tree.

To the question: Is there a way I can save a handle class in a way that its accessible in two separate sessions?

A horrible wrong example in C that get the point would be saving an address in a file and opening that file in another program to access the information there.

Is there a way to do this? Its a temporary fix while I'm not in the electronics yet.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: You want to share the same handle between multiple sessions? At the same time or just after each other?

Comment: @Matt Multiple sessions would be the best way to word it, I'll edit accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @Hovestar: You just want to read the data? Or one process reads, the other writes? Simultaneously or not? I don't understand the concept you want to apply.

Comment: I want to have both to have the ability to read and write. If it doesn't exist that's fine, but I'm just hoping for an easy way to do this.